# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got string in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF I am facing an issue, whenever I do a POST request on the endpoint, on the field "name" which is a text field I get an exception "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'TITLE'", but when I change the value of "name" to an integer the request is successful I don't understand it becauses name is TextField in model and why its mixing Id and Name field with each other. I have deleted the migration files from the Project and DB and re-run the Migrations, but still facing this issue.
Following is my code:

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_crated_by')
    name = models.TextField(max_length=225, blank=False, null=False)
    project_members = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='members', null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=225, default=''), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    objects = models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
class ProjectView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        project_name_exist = Project.verify_project_name(request.data['admin'], request.data['name'])
        if project_name_exist:
            return Response({'message': 'You already have a project with this name',
                             'status': status.HTTP_200_OK})
        serialized_project = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serialized_project.is_valid():
            serialized_project.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Project Created Successfully', 'status': status.HTTP_201_CREATED})
        else:
            return Response({'error': serialized_project.errors, 'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
```

serializer.py

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Please post your Project.verify_project_name(...) code

Answer (score 0):

A more generic and non-DIY solution is to use `UniqueTogetherValidator` on your serializer and let Django sort it out.

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Project.objects.all(),
                fields=['admin', 'name'],
                message='You already have a project with this name'
            )
        ]
```

And/or add it to the model for enforcing it on the database.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_crated_by')
    name = models.TextField(max_length=225, blank=False, null=False)
    project_members = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='members', null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=225, default=''), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("admin", "name")
```